# "Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean() "when trying to update database in ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation

Below is my index.php file with content I found on the internet.

I have written all my code and everything is working fine except that the form is not submitted and doesn't show the alert message that "Registration Completed Successfully".

Instead I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to  a member function execute() on boolean() on line
>   25

I have also created a tbl_register table in a database named "charu" that contains 5 columns with null values.

**HTML:**

```
<html>  
    <head>  
        <title>PHP Form Validation using Parsleys.js Library</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>  
        <div class="container">  
            <br />  
            <br />
   <br />
   <div class="table-responsive">  
    <h3 align="center">PHP Form Validation using Parsleys.js Library</h3><br />
    <div class="box">
     <form id="validate_form">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>First Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" placeholder="Enter First Name" required data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z]+$" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" class="form-control" />
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-6">
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Last Name</label>
         <input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required data-parsley-pattern="^[a-zA-Z ]+$" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" class="form-control" />
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="password">Password</label>
       <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required data-parsley-length="[8, 16]" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="cpassword">Confirm Password</label>
       <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password"data-parsley-equalto="#password" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" required class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <label for="cpassword">Website</label>
       <input type="text" id="website" name="website" placeholder="Website URL" data-parsley-type="url" data-parsley-trigger="keyup" class="form-control" />
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <div class="checkbox">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="check_rules" name="check_rules" required /> I Accept the Terms & Conditions</label>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
       <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success" />
      </div>
     </form>
    </div>
   </div>  
  </div>
    </body>  
</html>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>  
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('#validate_form').parsley();

    $('#validate_form').on('submit', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        if($('#validate_form').parsley().isValid())
        {
            $.ajax({
                url:"action.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:$(this).serialize(),
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
                    $('#submit').val('Submitting...');
                },
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#validate_form')[0].reset();
                    $('#validate_form').parsley().reset();
                    $('#submit').attr('disabled',false);
                    $('#submit').val('Submit');
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});  
</script>
```

**action.php file:**

```
<?php

sleep(5);

if(isset($_POST['first_name']))
{
    $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","charu");

    $data = array(
        ':first_name'  => $_POST['first_name'],
        ':last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
        ':email'   => $_POST['email'],
        ':password'   => $_POST['password'],
        ':website'   => $_POST['website']
    );

    $query = "
       INSERT INTO tbl_register 
       (first_name, last_name, email, password, website) 
       VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :website)
    ";
    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
    if($statement->execute($data))
    {
        echo 'Registration Completed Successfully...';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `bind_params();`

replace this

```
  $data = array(
    ':first_name'  => $_POST['first_name'],
    ':last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
    ':email'   => $_POST['email'],
    ':password'   => $_POST['password'],
    ':website'   => $_POST['website']
   );

   $query = "
   INSERT INTO tbl_register 
   (first_name, last_name, email, password, website) 
   VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :website)
   ";
   $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

   if($statement->execute($data))
   {
    echo 'Registration Completed Successfully...';
   }


  with


  $query = "
   INSERT INTO tbl_register 
   (first_name, last_name, email, password, website) 
   VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
   ";
   $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

   $statement->bind_param('sssss',$_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['password'],$_POST['website']);

   //here 's' in sssss stands for string and all your parameters are string so five 's' are added 

   if($statement->execute())
   {
    echo 'Registration Completed Successfully...';
   }
```

Comment: Thnq so much for the help. It is working perfectly :)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to print error yourself to see the actual cause.
Do this. After the if statement

```
else{
echo $connect->error;
echo $statement->error;
}
```

You can copy and use the code. I've modified. It works.

```
if(isset($_POST['first_name']))
{
 $connect = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "","charu");


  $first_name  = $_POST['first_name'];
  $last_name  = $_POST['last_name'];
  $email   = $_POST['email'];
  $password   = $_POST['password'];
  $website   = $_POST['website'];

 $query = "
 INSERT INTO tbl_register 
 (first_name, last_name, email, password, website) 
 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
 ";
 if(!$statement = $connect->prepare($query)){
echo $connect->error;
echo $statement->error;

}
else{
$statement->bind_param("sssss", $first_name, $lastname, $email, $password, $website);
If(statement->execute()){
  echo 'Registration Completed Successfully...';
 }
} }
```

Fee free to ask and lemme know the feedback.

Comment: I have copy this content and replace with the previous one and now it shows "Parse error syntax error in line 32 where execute method have to work. Wht to do now

Comment: And which one is the line 32?

Comment: I thought you said PDO. Change the **bindParam**  to **bind_param("s", $firstname)**

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the parameters to the SQL query and tell to the database what the parameters are.

```
// prepare sql and bind parameters
$query = "
 INSERT INTO tbl_register 
 (first_name, last_name, email, password, website) 
 VALUES (:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :website)
 ";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->bindParam(':first_name', $_POST['first_name']);
$statement->bindParam(':last_name', $_POST['last_name']);
$statement->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$statement->bindParam(':password', $_POST['password']);
$statement->bindParam(':website', $_POST['website']);

 if($statement->execute())
 {
    echo 'Registration Completed Successfully...';
 }
```